# Get link to PartialView in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, content-management-system, orchardcms, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to render a RazorView to string but in Orchard CMS, but I don't know how to get link to a partial view to get string.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

If in another MVC Project - not Orchard - it worked OK with the code:

```
string result = RenderRazorViewToString("~/Views/Home/PartialViewEmail.cshtml", null);
```

But in Orchard CMS, it doesn't know where to get that partialview.

What should I do ?

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 5):

The better solution however is to adopt the Orchard way of doing things, using shapes. If you do:

```
@Display.ViewEmail(SomeParameter: 42, SomeOtherParameter: "foo")
```

And then create a file in your theme under `/Views` named `ViewEmail.cshtml`, you can reference the parameters passed in as properties of `Model` if you need them. The call to `Display` will cause the rendering of the `ViewEmail` shape.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve that problem. It's very simple like below

```
PartialViewResult path = PartialView("PartialViewEmail");
string tmp = path.ViewName;
string result = RenderRazorViewToString(tmp, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've opted for an extension method like the following:

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static string RenderToString(this PartialViewResult partialView)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("An HTTP context is required to render the partial view to a string");
        }

        var controllerName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        var controller = (ControllerBase)ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, controllerName);

        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, controller);

        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialView.ViewName).View;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                view.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, view, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, tw), tw);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

It allows me to do the following:

```
var html = PartialView("SomeView").RenderToString();
```

If I still wanted to get the full path of the view for some reason I could do the following:

```
var path = ((BuildManagerCompiledView)view).ViewPath; // Will be something like "~/Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml"
```